# Custom Rails Environment running as Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a custom environment for my Rails 3.0 application running on Nginx. When trying to get the custom error pages (404 and 500) working, I face an issue: It seems Rails only uses public/500.html and public/404.html when the environment is called "production" and since my custom environment is called something else (next) it's not using those files.

How can I tell Rails that "next" is really a production environment?

Comment: Do you have `config.serve_static_assets = true` in the next.rb file?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included your config/environments/next.rb configuration file.